# apt-get upgrade: error 503

Tags: apt, upgrade

I'm stuck with upgrading Kubuntu 16.04. It begins upgrading, then stops for some time and gives an error 503. I've tried to download files manually from the repo, but despite the files present in the directory, I can't download them. `apt-get clean` and `apt-get upgrade --fix-missing` also doesn't solve this problem. How do I fix this error?

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  wine-staging wine-staging-amd64 wine-staging-i386:i386 winehq-staging
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 51.2 MB/54.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1064 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Err:1 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 wine-staging-amd64 amd64 2.20.0~xenial                                                                                                          
  503  first byte timeout
Err:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main i386 wine-staging-i386 i386 2.20.0~xenial
  503  first byte timeout
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/pool/main/wine-staging-amd64_2.20.0~xenial_amd64.deb  503  first byte timeout

E: Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/pool/main/wine-staging-i386_2.20.0~xenial_i386.deb  503  first byte timeout

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Edit: despite this problem has been resolved since the server has become up, I don't think that this question should be on hold, because some users can experience the same problem and find solution here. Just my opinion.

Comment: Please post outputs in English. You can switch the language for a single command by prefixing it with `LANG=C`, e.g. `LANG=C sudo apt upgrade`. Could you [edit] that? Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, the HTTP status code 503 stands for "Service unavailable" and is in the category of server errors. This means something is currently wrong on their side and you probably just have to wait until whatever is broken gets fixed by the domain owners. You might want to try and contact them to report the problem.

Comment: @ByteCommander OK, edited.

Comment: The server error appears to have been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
wine-staging-amd64_2.20.0~xenial_amd64.deb
wine-staging-i386_2.20.0~xenial_i386.deb
```

Those files were just posted on Nov 6, 2017 -- they either have some networking issue on their end or theses files haven't fully propagated.

Running these commands will not help:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The best solution is just to try again later, by then the 503 error will have resolved itself.